# Calling IMappingEngine.Map inside custom mapping

Tags: c#, automapper, circular-dependency

With AutoMapper, when using ConvertUsing to define a custom mapping for a type that is a container, I often need to call IMappingEngine.Map inside the mapping function. This is necessary because it allows-me to reuse the definition of the child mapping.

```
CreateMap<Order, OrderModel>()
    .ConvertUsing(o => new OrderModel(
        o.Id,
        o.ShippingAddress,
        mapper.Map<IList<OrderItemModel>>(o.Items)
    ));
```

In order to do this, I need a reference to IMappingEngine. When the mapping engine is being configured, I don't have a reference to it that can be captured in the ConvertUsing argument. A simple solution is to have a static reference to it somewhere, but I would like to avoid it.

Is there a way to get a reference to the current IMappingEngine inside a mapping that uses ConvertUsing?

Comment: just curious, why is this tagged as dependency-injection?

Comment: That's an error. Thanks for noticing it. I rewrote this question and removed part of it because it made it more complex. Basically this problem becomes more evident when using dependency-injection to create the mapper and its configuration.

Answer (score 3):

***This answer is based on your [original revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/9282819/1) which included additional code***

If you take a look at the article by Jimmy Bogard on [Automapper and IOC](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2009/05/12/automapper-and-ioc/) he notes the following:

> The MappingEngine, unlike our Configuration object, does not need any
>   special caching/lifetime behavior.  The MappingEngine is very
>   lightweight, as it’s really a bunch of methods doing interesting
>   things with Configuration.  MappingEngine can be singleton if we want,
>   but there’s no need.

(There is updated sample IOC code for the latest version of Automapper on [github](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/master/src/AutoMapperSamples/InversionOfControl.cs))

As long as your `ConfigurationStore` is a singleton and requests for `IConfiguration` and `IConfigurationProvider` from your DI container resolve to this singleton instance, the article (and code examples) advocates that is fine to create new instances of the `MappingEngine` when injected.

Based on the above, aside from not registering your `ConfigurationStore` as a singleton instance (I assume, I'm not familiar with ninject) and not binding this instance to the `IConfiguration` your final implementation of `MappingProfile` in your original revision is actually an acceptable solution. It is OK for this to not be the same `MappingEngine` instance.

However, going by your sample usage in your question it may be worth considering *Scenario 2* in the article. If you have no requirement to inject configuration throughout your application and only the `IMappingEngine`, then you can rely on the static `Mapper` class for the configuration and lifetime management. In summary your changes to adopt this would be:

1. Remove the `IConfigurationProvider` related wiring in the build-up of your container (in the `MappingModule`).
2. Switching your `MappingProfile` to use the static `Mapper` class

   ```
   CreateMap<Order, OrderModel>()
       .ConvertUsing(o => new OrderModel(
           o.Id,
           o.ShippingAddress,
           Mapper.Map<IList<OrderItemModel>>(o.Items) //use static Mapper class
   ));

   CreateMap<OrderItem, OrderItemModel>();
   ```
3. Adding the `Profile` to the `Mapper` (perhaps in the `MappingModule`?), and doing any other configuration through the `Mapper`:

   ```
   Mapper.AddProfile(new MappingProfile());
   ```
4. Binding `IMappingEngine` in the ninject container to the `Mapper.Engine` property.

Comment: The main problem is that, in order to create an IMappingEngine, I need an IConfiguration, but to create the IConfiguration, I need IMappingEngine. Using the static Mapper hides this problem but does not solve it. I can create an empty configuration, create a mapping engine with it, and then configure the configuration with the mapping engine, but that relies on the fact that MappingEngine accepts that the configuration changes after it is instantiated.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. The maps are just a series of lambdas executed at the time you map an instance. As long as the `MappingEngine` in your nested map is using the same `ConfigurationStore` that is being configured (i.e. a singleton) then it's not a problem at the time of mapping. It is the same reason you can define the `CreateMap`'s out of order of their usage, as you have done in your `Profile`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the static `Mapper.Map<IList<OrderItemModel>>(o.Items)` instead of your instance of `IMappingEngine`.  It contains a reference to the engine that is lazily instantiated the first time it is used.

Comment: Yes, that works, but I would rather avoid using the static Mapper class.

Comment: same, didn't find a solution either