# Map complex type to flat type in AutoMapper

Tags: automapper

I have a complex object like:

```cs
public class BusinessUnit
{
        public TradingDesk TradingDesk { get; }
        public string Division { get; }

        public BusinessUnit(string division, TradingDesk tradingDesk)
        {
            Division = division;
            TradingDesk = tradingDesk;
        }
}
```

I want to map this to the flat type:

```cs
public class Row
{
   //TradingDesk properties
   public string TraderFirstName { get; set; }
   public string TraderLastName { get; set; }
   public string TradingDeskName { get; set; }

   public string Division { get; set; }
}
```

I have already configured `AutoMapper` for `TradingDesk`:

```cs
CreateMap<TradingDesk, Row>().ForMember(vm => vm.TradingDeskName, op => op.MapFrom(src => src.Name));
```

so the following test is passing:

```cs
[Test]
public void Should_Map_TradingDesk_To_Row()
{
    var tradingDesk = Fixture.Create<TradingDesk>();

    var mapped = AutoMapper.Map<Row>(tradingDesk);

    mapped.TradingDeskName.Should()
            .Be(tradingDesk.Name);
    mapped.TraderFirstName.Should()
            .Be(tradingDesk.Trader.FirstName);
    mapped.TraderLastName.Should()
            .Be(tradingDesk.Trader.LastName);
}
```

But when I try to map `BusinessUnit` to `Row` I am having to reconfigure `AutoMapper` for `TradingDesk` as such:

```cs
CreateMap<BusinessUnit, Row>()
   .ForMember(vm => vm.TradingDeskName, op => op.MapFrom(src => src.TradingDesk.Name))
   .ForMember(vm => vm.TraderFirstName, op => op.MapFrom(src => src.TradingDesk.Trader.FirstName))
   .ForMember(vm => vm.TraderLastName, op => op.MapFrom(src => src.TradingDesk.Trader.LastName));
```

I expect that `AutoMapper` should use the already configured source & destination type mapping when it needs to map `TradingDesk` to `Row` while mapping `BusinessUnit`. This way I can build the configuration from the smallest to the largest type while flattening out a complex object without having to define mapping for each individual member in the flattened type.

Answer (score 1):

Actual syntax might differ because I'm using AutoMapper in a static manner, but the principle remains the same:

```cs
Mapper.CreateMap<BusinessUnit, Row>()
      .ConvertUsing(source => Mapper.Map<TradingDesk, Row>(source.TradingDesk));
```

Comment: But I don't have an `IMapper` instance that's created from the config there; so your code blows up with `AutoMapperMappingException`

Comment: Looking at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9404417/1558010), your options might be limited if you're not relying on the static Mapper

Answer (score 0):

First of I think your map for trading desk would be just

```
CreateMap<TradingDesk, Row>();
```

If memory serves me right, since your destination member matches source member name when ".' are removed then you do not need to specify it explicitly.

If you change your Row class to this

```
public class Row
{
   //TradingDesk properties
   public string TradingDeskTraderFirstName { get; set; }
   public string TradingDeskTraderLastName { get; set; }
   public string TradingDeskName { get; set; }

   public string Division { get; set; }
}
```

your map would be

```
CreateMap<BusinessUnit, Row>();
```

If you are never going to map to TradingDesk, then remove that map.

If this is defined in some Profile, you can also say

```
RecognizePrefixes("TradingDesk");
```

and then you do not need to change your Row class.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to create a special converters or property resolvers you can perform the second mapping after the map of the main object, e.g.:

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<TradingDesk, Row>()
        .ForMember(vm => vm.TradingDeskName, op => op.MapFrom(src => src.Name));
    cfg.CreateMap<BusinessUnit, Row>()
        .AfterMap((businessUnit, row) => { Mapper.Map(businessUnit.TradingDesk, row); });
});

var source = new BusinessUnit("division", new TradingDesk { TraderFirstName = "FirstName", TraderLastName = "LastName", Name = "DeskName" });

var dest = Mapper.Map<Row>(source);
```

In this case, the object has been mapped without creating a new instance.